# Accessing session in Spring validate method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator, struts-validation

I am migrating my Struts application to Spring. While migrating I came across the validate method of Struts which needs to be migrated in Spring. The Struts validate method accepts parameters as **ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest req** and using the req object session was created in validate method of Struts. 
But the validate method of Spring only accepts parameters: **Object target, Errors errors** . So how can I create a session object in the validate method of Spring ?
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: method to method mapping may not be the right approach to migrating an application from one framework to another. I would recommend creating a simple helloworld application in Spring and migrating functionality not methods. You may also want to look at spring form input validation guide here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the session by doing the following

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
```

I do agree with Prashant that a one for one migration might not be the best way forward but without more context its hard to say

Comment: I do agree with you all, I am not doing one to one mapping from Struts to Spring, I am refactoring the code where ever necessary while migrating, but the session object was mandatory in the validate method as some validation has to be done with session attributes. @Sean Carrol : Thanks for the solution, will run the code and see if that works.  Thanks!